# How Partition a complex table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, partitioning

I have a table called `CHECKINOUT` in SQL Server, the table has the following columns:

```
PASSID  CHECKTIME               CHECKTYPE   UID
--------------------------------------------------
PS3 2015-08-05 01:12:02.100     0       CAA0322
PS3 2015-08-06 02:17:02.310     1       CAA0322
PS4 2015-08-03 01:02:03.200     0       CAA0322
PS4 2015-08-03 11:11:01.233     1       CAA0322
PS3 2015-08-02 11:11:01.210     0       CAA0322
PS3 2015-08-02 12:02:04.147     1       CAA0322
PS1 2015-09-05 11:11:01.210     0       CAA0322
PS1 2015-09-05 01:12:09.010     1       CAA0322
```

`PASSID` is the pass given everytime someone accesses the premises and the moment they are allowed in, their checkin time is registered and the Checktype turns to 0

```
   CHECKTYPE=0
```

When they checkout of the premises, the time they checkout is also registered again in the checktime but this time the 
checktype flag turns to 1

```
   CHECKTYPE=0
```

now at the end of the day i would like to see a report of each pass regardless of how many times it has come in and out with an output like

```
PASSID  CheckInTime             CheckOutTime                     UID
PS1 2015-08-05 01:12:02.100     2015-08-06 02:17:02.310     CAA0322
PS3 2015-08-05 01:12:02.100     2015-08-06 02:17:02.310     CAA0322
PS3 2015-08-02 11:11:01.210     2015-08-02 12:02:04.147     CAA0322
PS4 2015-08-03 01:02:03.200     22015-08-03 11:11:01.233    CAA0322
```

The above result display assumes the following

- CheckInTime is the first checktime with  checktype =0 of that ID in desc
- CheckOutTime is the first checktime with checktype =1 of that ID in desc

I tried using partitions but I have failed, I can only return one record, but I would love to see all records my code was below but it only returns one record, I would love to return all without specifying any passid

```
declare @PassID varchar(30)='PS3';

with LastEntryData(PASSID, CHECKTIME, CHECKTYPE, GateID, UID)
as 
(
    select top 2 
        c.PASSID, c.CHECKTIME, c.CHECKTYPE, c.GateID, c.UID     
    from 
        CHECKINOUT c
    where 
        c.PASSID = @PassID
    order by 
        c.CHECKTIME desc
    ),
    CheckInTime(CHECKTIME) as
    (
        select 
            i.CHECKTIME 
        from 
            LastEntryData i
        where 
            i.CHECKTYPE = 0),
    CheckOutTime(CHECKTIME) as
    (
        select 
            i.CHECKTIME 
        from 
            LastEntryData i
        where 
            i.CHECKTYPE = 1)
select 
    l.PASSID, CheckInTime = i.CHECKTIME,
    CheckOutTime = o.CHECKTIME, l.UID 
from 
    LastEntryData l, CheckInTime i, CheckOutTime o
group by 
    l.PASSID, l.GateID, l.UID, i.CHECKTIME, o.CHECKTIME
```

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 20 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: Partitions have nothing to do with querying, they handle physical storage.

Comment: any way i can get an output as the above is welcome

Comment: Please explain GateID...it is not in the sample data, but is in the SQL and results...  ?

Comment: Data doesn't match your expected output. In the data, PS1 did not check in at all on 2015-08-05.

Answer (score 0):

Let's make a table. (You'll get more answers if *you* do this.)

```
create table checkinout (
  passid char(3) not null,
  checktime timestamp not null default current_timestamp,
  checktype integer not null check (checktype in (1, 0)),
  uid char(7) not null
);

insert into checkinout values
('PS3', '2015-08-05 01:12:02.100',     0,       'CAA0322'),
('PS3', '2015-08-06 02:17:02.310',     1,       'CAA0322'),
('PS4', '2015-08-03 01:02:03.200',     0,       'CAA0322'),
('PS4', '2015-08-03 11:11:01.233',     1,       'CAA0322'),
('PS3', '2015-08-02 11:11:01.210',     0,       'CAA0322'),
('PS3', '2015-08-02 12:02:04.147',     1,       'CAA0322'),
('PS1', '2015-09-05 11:11:01.210',     0,       'CAA0322'),
('PS1', '2015-09-05 01:12:09.010',     1,       'CAA0322');
```

I'm going to make some educated guesses, because your sample data doesn't match up with your expected output.

This query (in PostgreSQL) returns all the check in times.

```
select uid, passid, checktime as time_in
from checkinout
where checktype = 0
order by uid, passid, checktime;
```

```
uid       passid  time_in
--
CAA0322   PS1     2015-09-05 11:11:01.21
CAA0322   PS3     2015-08-02 11:11:01.21
CAA0322   PS3     2015-08-05 01:12:02.1
CAA0322   PS4     2015-08-03 01:02:03.2
```

A subquery will return the checkout times. This will run on just about any SQL dbms.

```
select 
  t1.uid, t1.passid, t1.checktime,
  (select min(checktime) 
   from checkinout 
   where uid = t1.uid 
     and passid = t1.passid 
     and checktime >= t1.checktime
     and checktype = 1) as time_out
from checkinout t1
where checktype = 0
order by t1.uid, t1.passid, t1.checktime;
```

```
uid       passid  time_in                 time_out
--
CAA0322   PS1     2015-09-05 11:11:01.21  
CAA0322   PS3     2015-08-02 11:11:01.21  2015-08-02 12:02:04.147
CAA0322   PS3     2015-08-05 01:12:02.1   2015-08-06 02:17:02.31
CAA0322   PS4     2015-08-03 01:02:03.2   2015-08-03 11:11:01.233
```

Bad data explains the NULL.

If your data and your people are very well-behaved, and if your platform supports analytic functions, you can use either lead() or lag() to bring the pieces together. (I think SQL Server 2012+ supports lead() and lag().)

```
with checkinout_extended as (
  select uid, passid, checktime as time_in, checktype,
  lead(checktime) over (partition by uid, passid order by checktime, checktype) as time_out
  from checkinout
)
select uid, passid, time_in, time_out
from checkinout_extended
where checktype = 0
order by uid, passid, time_in;
```

Comment: Mike Sherrill  you just saved my day. the subquery is what i was looking for that can return a pass with also checkin even when that person has not yet checked out